# send subscription response as parameter to method Angular/rxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

I Have a subscription like below in my Child-Component.

```
ngOnInit{
    this.subscription = this._cs.recieveData.subscribe((res) => {
    this.data= res;
  });
    UseDatafromSubs(this.data){
    //do Something
    }
}
```

I have another method in child-Component like above (**UseDatafromSubs**) which accepts my subscription response as parameter:

In my ParentComponent i am updating the service like below:

```
senddata(){
     this._cs.send(sendData);
}
```

I am able to send and receive updated Data from Parent to Child, but my **useDataFromSubs** is not being called when the new subscription data comes,to use the data, its not taking the subscription response as parameter. I tried using add method like below:

```
 this.subscription = this._cs.recieveData.subscribe((res) => {
    this.data= res;
  }).add(()=>this.UseDatafromSubs(this.data));
```

but no use.

can somebody please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like wrong pattern. Don't pass around subscriptions, pass around observables.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just call the method you want inside the subscribe block?
e.g.

```
ngOnInit{
    this.subscription = this._cs.recieveData.subscribe((res) => {
    this.data= res;
    this.UseDatafromSubs(res);
  })
}
```